# Could a Skyscraper's Skeleton Be Stainless?

Tags: construction, metals

The official definition of "stainless steel" is a steel alloy where 10.5% consists of chromium, allowing it to withstand corrosion a lot better than carbon steel.  With this sort of advantage, you'd expect to see stainless steel being the very bones of a skyscraper's skeleton.

But skyscrapers consist of regular carbon steel rather than stainless.  Why is that?  Why don't we see stainless steel being used to build skyscrapers?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26582/a-tougher-longer-lasting-skyscraper

Comment: @DanSmolinske First, I would like to think the same author wouldn't post a duplicate to their own question. Second, that question explicitly mentions stainless as not a solution, while this one seeks to know why it's not a solution.

Comment: @Frostfyre: I didn't even notice the authors, oops.  I just remembered the discussion, and I thought there were a few answers that directly addressed stainless steel in skyscrapers.

Comment: For a related fun, search for carbon steel vs. stainless and read all the opinions on how different high-carbon steel is compared to stainless in the knife market.  Making a skyscraper is not the same thing as a knife, but they do a really nice job of pointing out just how different the material properties are between carbon and stainless steels.

Comment: I vote to close - this would be more suited to engineering.stackexchange.com than world building.

Answer (score 10):

Chromium is a more expensive metal, so while alloying it with steel increases its resistance to corrosion it also increases its cost. Since the metal is buried in concrete and walls that aren't exposed to the moisture in air, it simply doesn't make sense to spend money on a stainless steel.

Stainless steel is better used for finished surfaces, or things like knives, where you want the material to be shiny and resistant to corrosion and rust.

Comment: Good answer.  I am new to forging but doesn't chromium also make the steel more brittle?

Comment: I just read in an article saying that the metal that made up the skeleton of the SS Titanic had too much sulfur, and THAT made the steel brittle.

Comment: @JohnWDailey - The Titanic's problems were due to the iceberg, not the quality of metal. If you ram 52,000 tons of ship into an iceberg at 23 knots, you're gonna make quite a mess of the ship regardless of the grade of steel - even most icebreakers or military ships would struggle at that speed.

Comment: http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/1997/12/971227000141.htm

Answer (score 4):

The steel is buried inside the concrete and protected from the elements by that concrete. Without being exposed to oxygen or water from the air it can't rust, so there is no advantage to be gained by using stainless steel...

Answer (score 1):

Ferroconcrete isn't perfect. Water does get in causing the steel reinforcement to rust, bits break off the concrete, eventually the building fails and has to be demolished. Many true skyscrapers aren't ferroconcrete, they are a framework of pure steel girders kept dry by a waterproof roof and cladding. They'll last for as long as the building is maintained.

The other enemy of such a building is fire.  The girders have to be wrapped in glassfibre or mineral wool (formerly, asbestos!) to prevent them softening and failing should the contents of the building catch fire. I suspect this is why no rich person's ego trip has been a stainless steel skyscraper. You'd not be able to expose the stainless steel, and if hidden, why bother?

Comment: This first part is actually wrong.
Water does get into the concrete, but provided the cover of concrete over the steel is sufficient (typically in the range of 25mm), the water turns very basic (by the concrete), thus preventing the steel from corroding.
Only when you have cracks or insufficient concrete cover does the steel inside the structure (continue to) rust.

Answer (score 1):

Regular steel is fully sufficient for the job.  When water passes through concrete, it becomes strongly basic. When it reaches the steel it is already so basic it does not lead to (continued) corrosion of the steel.

Only when the concrete cover is insufficient, either by poor design or poor workmanship, or due to damage the water will not spend enough time to pass through the concrete to become sufficiently basic. After that, the steel will rust, which adds oxygen to the iron atoms, thus increasing their volume, and consequently forcing open more of the concrete structure.

The steel part in the concrete is intended to withstand tensile forces. And you need a lot of steel in any reasonably sized building.
Chromium makes the steel more brittle (i.e. less able to do its job), and a lot more expensive.

That's why you never see chromium steel in reinforced concrete.